# Check if link is from an external Domain

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-5, redirect, http-redirect

I'm Working with Laravel and jquery. I have e-commerce and I have a list of my products some of them are on my web site and some of them Don't I need to **redirect the ones that are inside** my web and **open a new tab the other**s.
for example:

```
<a href="www.MYWEB.COM" > MY PRODUCTS</a>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Producs from other website </a>
```

is it possible? So far I have this. I really need help.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
   <div class="header-items">My Products<span class="count-items ml-1">{{count($notifications)}}</span></div>
     @foreach ($notifications as $item)
       <a href="{{ $item->url }}"  class="idNote" data-note="{{ $item->id }}" style="color: #000000;" data-redirect="{{$item->url}}">
         <div id="note-{{ $item->id }}" class="item {{$item->isOpen? 'not-read' : '' }}"  >
              <p class="mb-0 font-medium">{{ $item->titulo }}</p>
              <p class="mb-0">{{ $item->texto }}</p>
              <span class="point-not-read"></span>
         </div>
       </a>
     @endforeach                   
</div>
```

my jquery

```
<script>
    $('.idNote').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var noteId = $(this).attr('data-note');
        var redirecTwo = $(this).attr('data-redirect');
        console.log(noteId);
        $.ajax({
            url : "{{ route('readit') }}",
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                jsNoteId : noteId
            },
            beforeSend : function(){
                $('#note-'+noteId).removeClass('not-read');
                //window.location = redirecTwo;
                window.open(redirecTwo, '_blank');
            },
            success : function(r){                    
                console.log(r);                    
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if href includes name of your website

```
$('.idNote').click((e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   let href = $(e.target).attr('href');
   let mySiteName = 'https://NAME OF YOUR SITE.com';
   if(href.includes(mySiteName){
      window.open(href, '_self')
   }else{
      window.open(href, '_blank')
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create actual URL of href attribute
2. Check if `url.hostname` is matching to our site's hostname
3. If matching, then open window in current tab
4. If not, then open window in new tab

Eg.

```
$('.idNote').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    href = href.startsWith("http") ? href : "http://"+href;
    href = new URL(href);
    if((href.hostname).startsWith("www.myweb.com")){ //use this if statement in your beforeSend function
    window.open(href);
}else{
    window.open(href,"_blank");
}
    });
```